# problem populating dropdownlist of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
              OnRowDataBound="grdViewCInfo_RowDataBound"

             >

        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <Columns>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Concert Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Concert_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Concert_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="40px"></HeaderStyle>

        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAddr" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddr" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Address") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="40px"></HeaderStyle>

        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pincode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPincode" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Pincode") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPincode" runat="server" Text=' <%#Bind("Pincode") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcountry" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" >                                               
                </asp:DropDownList>  

                </EditItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Concert Date and Time" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Concert_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Concert_Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="False">
                            <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                     </asp:CommandField>
                     <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true">
                         <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                     </asp:CommandField> 

        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you forgot to tell us the problem :)

Comment: @naveen, I'm guessing the problem is indicated by the comments in the code but, perhaps I assume too much.

Comment: @jodrell: i dont get it. did you? this is what confuse me. ddl.DataSource=ds//error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. you should see that row count is greater than 0.

Comment: @user755230: are you using templatefield

Comment: @naveen, the 'ds.Tables[0].Rows' bit works. The 'ddl.DataSource' bit fails because 'ddl' is null.

Comment: yes row count is greater than 0

Comment: Add the GridView markup the your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part of this should be done at RowDataBound also.

Here is some sample code

```
private static DataSet ds;
private const string query = "select * from tblcountrynames";
protected void grdViewCInfo_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdViewCInfo.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    //guessing that this is your databind event
    dbLoad();
}
protected void grdViewCInfo_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        //your ddl
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCountry");

        PopulateCountries(ddl, query);
        //grdViewCInfo.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[4].Controls.Add(ddl);
    }
}

private void PopulateCountries(DropDownList ddl, string query)
{
    if(ds!= null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)

        MySqlConnection objMycon1 = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
        //commenting open; as adapter doesn't need connection to be open
        //objMycon1.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query, objMycon1);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        objMycon1.Close();
        objMycon1.Dispose();//comment if objMycon1 is not IDisposible

    }

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddl.DataSource = ds;
        ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This is how it should be done.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i m wonder if ds in populate country is initially null how will it go in

Comment: as soon as i remove that initial if condition it worked. thnx  great help

Answer (score 1):

What does `(DropDownList)grdViewCInfo.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("ddlCountry");` return , is `ddl` set?

I reckon not. Perhaps there is no "ddlCountry" control in that cell.

Its a curious coincidence that the line,

```
//grdViewCInfo.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[4].Controls.Add(ddl);
```

is commented out below.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a drop down list in your EditItemTemplate?

**Edit:** I don't think you are actually in edit mode in the RowEditing event.  If you move your code down to the RowCommand,

Then check for the Edit command.  Wrap your code in something like,

```
if(e.CommandName == "Edit")
{

// do your edit here.

}
```

Though keep your `grdViewCInfo.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;` line, as you need that there.

Comment: @user755230: hmmm.. please be more elaborate in the question itself

Comment: Added more, from Edit on down